# Javascript illustrator for aspx in visual studio 2019

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I install Microsoft-vs2019 to develop my web application in asp.net web-forms.

Now in ASPX file editor, Javascript methods from jQuery or other js files not known. Please help me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The picture you provided shows that you have intellisense. It implies that jQuery methods are known by your IDE. Can you explain the your problem more?

Comment: Hi metti.
This image shown that all jQuery methods not listed in illustrator.

Comment: Also other .js files in directories in Project, when referenced in ".aspx" file, them methods not shown in editor.

In vs2013, 2015 all methods listed. please see next image print screen...

Answer (score 0):

In vs2013, all methods are listed... but in vs2017 and 2019 not shown.

[image: VisualStudio Jquery code]